# react-router-dom with multiple query strings does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react router. I use react-router-dom 4.2.2 
in my router set up I have:

```
<Route path={"/confirmuser/:confirmation_code/:username"} component={ConfirmUser} />
```

and here is a sample url I am trying to achieve:

```
localhost:3003/confirmuser?confirmation_code=986797&username=5f1
```

As you see I am trying to send multiple query strings.
in the confirmUser I read the query strings as follow:

```
    console.log(this.props.match.params.confirmation_code);
    console.log(this.props.match.params.username);
```

However I do not even get directed to this component and it seems react is not able to route to that page properly.
Any idea?

Comment: try with `path="/confirmuser/:confirmation_code/:username"`, without the `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-router v4 doesn't parse query strings anymore, so you either have to do the parsing yourself (not recommended), or use a package like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string). An easy way to access the values is with a wrapper component, like this:

```
import * as queryString from 'query-string';
..

const WrappedConfirmUser = () => {
  const {confirmation_code, username} = queryString.parse(location.search);
  return <ConfirmUser confirmation_code={confirmation_code} username={username}/>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to map search-params to path segments?

The Route you defined will try to match the path, not the search params.
Try:
`http://localhost:3003/confirmuser/986797/5f1`
and the values will be in `this.props.match.params` like this:

```
{
  confirmation_code: '986797',
  username: '5f1',
}
```

if you still want to read the search params, you can access them from `this.props.location.search`, but react-router will not match them to a route for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your path doesn't match your url.

It matches `localhost:3003/confirmuser/986797/5f1`

Then you can access params using extra prop `match`:

`{props.match.params.confirmation_code}`

`{props.match.params.username}`